# MongoDB, should I authenticate using database users or a user table

Tags: mongodb

Im new to MongoDB (MySQL user) and Im building a SAAS application (Node.js). Each instance of the software will be installed on its own containerized setup and have a single database per customer.

Each customer will require various user roles for the database (main admin, group admin, individual etc) and Im wondering if I can use the MongoDB users and roles rather than creating a separate user table and using something like Passport.js for authentication.

Is it safe to use database users and roles for authentication?

Havent tried anything yet, still in R&D mode and MongoDB is a new learning curve for me.

Comment: Be sure you don't conflate database users with application users. The database users allow your application or a client tool to connect and make CRUD operations. Mongodb has pre-defined roles that you can assign to these users. However, things like passport.js are for handling your application users so you would definitely want to create a collection for those users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you like to achieve. MongoDB supports standard authentication methods username/password, X509 certificates, LDAP and Kerberos tickets (LDAP and Kerberos are only available at MongoDB Enterprise Edition). There is no reason to re-invent the wheel.

MongoDB also provide a fine-grained privilege model, see [Privilege Actions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/privilege-actions/) or [Built-In Roles](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/built-in-roles/).

Of course, if you like to manage **application** roles and privileges, then the MongoDB security model cannot support you.

Comment: Its more about the data structure and access to it in a hierarchical way. Company admins accessing company data and customer data, then customers only accessing their own data etc. So admin roles get access to all tables and lower roles access only get access to their own tables. I think you've essentially answered the question through.